# getting 'Missing calls inside every { ... } block' when using mokk

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm using MockK as mock library for kotlin, for some reason I get an error on the `every{}` line.

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

this is my test class

```
internal class TestClass {

  private val service: MyService = mockk(relaxed = true)
  private val dao: MyDao = mockk(relaxed = true)
  private val repository: MyRepository = MyRepositoryImp(
    service = service,
    dao = dao,
  )

  @Test
  fun test() = runBlocking {
    val expected = SOMETHING

    every { repository.getValues() } returns flowOf(SOMETHINGELSE) // crash

    assertEquals(1, 1)
  }
}
```

`MyService` is just a retrofit interface

```
internal interface MyService {

  @GET("123")
  suspend fun getRemoteData(): Response<SOMECLASS>

}
```

Anyone has any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've instantiated the repository as a real instance. That means that it'll actually execute the code inside its implementation and that's known as the 'subject under test'.

But `every { ... } returns ...`  needs a mockk instance.

So in your example, it should be

`every { service.getRemoteData() } returns ...`
or
`every { dao.someMethod() } returns ...`